# Safari extension has content security policy error with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, safari

Can I resolved this??

Try code:

```
firebase.database().ref('name')
```

Error message:

> Refused to load
>   https://${my-firebase-id}/.lp?start=t&ser=23326461&cb=1&v=5 because it
>   does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security
>   Policy.